# Low-memory representation of paths in a 3D space

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, 3d, path-finding

I have a robot that can move in a 3D space (say 500m×500m×300m) with obstacles attached to a computer, and I'm trying to find a way to make it able to go back home.

A standard A* would work well, but the problem I have is that the robot has very little memory left (about 20kB) and that the connection with the computer can be lost at any moment and yet I always want to be able to go home as optimally as possible.

That means I simply do not have enough memory to simply have the space representation in the robot memory if I use a standard 3D array of identical node size (a 1m³ resolution would result in 75M cases).

I see two solutions to this:

- Either there is a way to represent the 3D space using much less memory and then be able to use a pathfinding algorithm on this space.
- Or I can pre-compute every path on the computer and send those paths to the drone so that it only has to follow them if needed.

Is there a data structure or algorithm that would help with either solutions? (Or simply a better solution?)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to map the whole space? Couldn't you just map the obstacles?

Comment: I just have to be able to go home without hitting anything, the rest is free.

Comment: By 3D, you mean that robot can fly, or there are just several floors ?

Comment: It can fly, it's a drone.

Comment: Just keep track of how you got there, and reverse the path?

Comment: If most of the space is free, you could use an Octree representation. [This presentation](http://rakaposhi.eas.asu.edu/quadtree-pplan-talk-unc.ppt) talks about using Quadtrees and could be a good starting point.

Comment: A large portion of the question depends on how many obstacles there are. 20kB isn't a huge amount of space tho'.

Comment: The drone will be performing missions that can include going further away from home then back, or simply making circles. So following blindly the path is far from ideal. However maybe optimizing the path to find a good enough return way can work. The biggest problem I see is if the drone went further away then closer. I will have no information to know if I can cross back straight on the previous path without going all the way back.

Comment: (If "reverse path", you could use some clever logic to avoid the complete reversal, if you move to one point and then back to the same point, you can remove that part)

Comment: How do you know where to go in the first place? How do you know where obstacles are on the way there?

Comment: For the 3D space, it's going to be following the terrain with a 300m ceiling, and a couple of exclusion zones going all the way from ground to sky. So it's going to be mostly one big zone with a few holes in it.

Comment: The path/missions are precomputed on the computer which holds all the terrain information, obstacles and all. Waypoints are then transferred to the drone which follows them blindly, it has no idea of its surrounding.

Comment: Sounds like a fun job. And based on your memory constraints, I see no choice but to precompute the possible paths from any of the mission waypoints to home. So when contact is lost, the drone either turns back to the previous waypoint, or proceeds to the next waypoint, and then follows a precomputed path home.

Comment: What level of customization does the drone have? Could you not make it so that the drone follows a line that has weights applied to it to give it some flexibility? So it would follow a bezier curve for a path, for instance. That way you can give each object a bounding circle. Check where the line falls in bounding circle and calculate a weight to alter the lines path. The drone would then only need to store the calculated weights and the waypoints and then calculate the line itself given the weights and waypoints.

Comment: M. Davies: If I understand correctly your comment, the obstacles would be represented by volumes. I then do a straight line from start to goal, and then curve the line if it intersects one of those volumes?

Comment: Correct, seeing as it is the computer that will be determining how the drone will try to avoid the objects you would calculate the weights on the computer based on how the line intersects with these volumes until you find a suitable curve to avoid the volumes and then send the weights plus the waypoints for each curved line to the drone.

All the drone would need to do then is use the weights and waypoints it was given to calculate the curve for itself and follow it. How you go about determining a suitable curved paths on the computer is then entirely up to you.

Comment: While I can't see it making a huge difference since it's only 3D values, it might be worth checking out for future using [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) for compression data with many variables/features to a smaller scale.

Comment: I suppose you could just calculate the volumes on the computer and send the waypoints plus the volumes and the position of the volumes to the drone and then get the drone to work out the best curves to avoid each volume. But that would depend entirely on the drones ability to do calculations. It would be cheaper for it to already know the weights and then just perform the curved line algorithm rather than having to work out the weights itself. But it is up to you really. If the drone can do that sort of thing it would be a viable pursuit.

Comment: That's the direction I think I will go towards for now. I don't really know yet how powerful (or not) the CPU is, but I should be able to cut the work into smaller parts anyway if needed. Thanks!